# jquery.ajax code that works in firefox but fails in all other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook

the code is here http://jsfiddle.net/assuredlonewolf/vHC9A/20/

I have no clue what is going on!

I know the url that is being called is not the problem, I make sure I get a new url when I open the code in a new browser since it is a new session and the Facebook's access token changes

Comment: Your access token is not valid in other browsers as you're not logged in, in the other browsers.

Comment: No, I make sure I get the right access token

Comment: When accessing your url, it says the session has expired. `{
   "error": {
      "message": "Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time 1332122400. The current unix time is 1332122905.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190
   }
}`

Comment: so why doesn't expire for firefox

Comment: Hmm, that is odd. I tested in FireFox and works. I will investigate further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firefox also it says

{
   "error": {
      "message": "Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time 1332122400. The current unix time is 1332123847.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190
   }
}

This may be your access token problem but for talking about your function

```
        function createFriendsUi(elem)
```

It displayed some thing like INVALID character in Line 52 by IE and Chrome consol said Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

there was illegal white space character, i don't know where, but when i re-wrote your function it worked fine in chrome and even in IE also.

your function after re-writing

```
      function createFriendsUi(elem)
        {
         var container = document.getElementById(elem);
         for (i=0;i<fbUser.friends.allNamesAndIds.length; i++) {
        var info = fbUser.friends.allNamesAndIds[i].split('||');
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        var image = document.createElement('img')
        var name = document.createElement('p');
        var label = document.createElement('label')
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.value = 'compare';
        input.type = 'submit'
        label.className = 'uiButton uiButtonConfirm';
        name.innerHTML = info[0];
        div.className = 'ppp';
        image.src = ' http://graph.facebook.com/' + info[1] + '/picture ';
        label.appendChild(input);
        div.appendChild(name);
        div.appendChild(image)
        div.appendChild(label);
        container.appendChild(div);
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you send me the rewrite of the function please

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting a page with a token that has already expired and Facebook returns

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time 1332122400. The current unix time is 1332123213.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190
   }
}
```

Comment: try it in firefox and see what happens

Comment: @JamesFair did it and does the same.